# how to use code first to create columnstore index in EF Core

Tags: ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1, columnstore

We want to start a new project and we decided to use Columnstore index along with clustered Index in some of the Tables from beginning, how can we do this with Code First EF Core 3.1?

Answer (score 0):

- you should change primary key to non cluster index:

  ```
  entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).IsClustered(false);
  ```
- then add a manual migration to migrations folder I add a file with name `30000000000001_AddMyColumnStoreIndex.cs` and add the following code in file

```cs
using DDFHandler;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [DbContext(typeof(MyApplicationContext))]
    [Migration("30000000000001_AddMyColumnStoreIndex")]
    public class V1_AddMyColumnStoreIndex : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up([NotNullAttribute] MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [cci] ON [sch].[TableName]");
        }
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

> be careful that you should replace **[sch].[TableName]** with your table name and schema